# chrome.app.getDetails() returns null

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to get the version of my extension at run-time using `chrome.app.getDetails().version` and noticed that `chrome.app.getDetails()` returns `null`. Surprisingly, there is no talk about this in the online community and the function isn't even documented by the Google folks. Is there a permission I am missing? I do have `tabs` enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Very old... I know
But in case if someone is looking for this, you can have your extension version *reading* the manifest file with [`chrome.runtime`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) API and the [`getManifest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest) Method.

Ex. in your background script:

```
var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
var current_version = manifest.version;

console.info('Current Version: ', current_version);
```

**The object returned is a serialization of the full manifest file**, so you can get all the info in the `manifest file`

So.. if you want for example all *and only* the `matches` of your `content_scripts`... for say something...

```
for(var i in manifest.content_scripts) {
  console.log(manifest.content_scripts[i]['matches']));
}
```

*Note: Stable since Chrome 22*

Answer (score 2):

It's undocumented because they might be moving `getDetails` to a different part of the API -- see [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111354). It's currently working on my copy of Chrome (beta channel), but I wouldn't be surprised if they've disabled it in a newer release. In the meantime you can just do an AJAX query to get the `manifest.json` of your extension -- you can get its URI using `chrome.extension.getURL("manifest.json")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using to pull the current version.

```
    var manifest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    manifest.open("get", "/manifest.json", true);
    manifest.onreadystatechange = function (e) { if (manifest.readyState == 4) {console.log(JSON.parse(manifest.responseText).version)} };
    manifest.send({});
```